# Inotify to monitor a file notifies twice, even if the file is modified once

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, inotify

I am using inotify to monitor the a file, but am facing an issue when ever the monitored file is changed (file.xml), it notifies twice even though the modification is done once (am opening the file using vim writing to it and am closing the file),an i also see that sometimes it just notifies once and in majority times, it notifies twice, can i get some input regarding as to what i am doing wrong in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

const char *file_path = "/home/file.xml";

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
int length, i;
int fd;
int wd;
char buffer[BUF_LEN];
fd = inotify_init();

if ( fd < 0 ) {
    perror( "inotify_init" );
}

wd = inotify_add_watch(fd,
        file_path,
        IN_ALL_EVENTS);

if(wd < 0) {
    perror ("inotify_add_watch");

   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(1)
{
    length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );

    if ( length < 0 ) {
        perror( "read" );
    }
    i = 0;
    while ( i < length ) {
        struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];
        if ( event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
            printf( "The file %s was modified.\n", file_path );
            break;
        }
        i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
    }
}

( void ) inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
( void ) close( fd );

exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps vim is issuing 2 write() calls for your file ? Even though you did 1 change in a text editor, the text editor might perform a lot of work in order to store that change on the disk.

Comment: Yeah - it might rename the old version to '.tmp' temporarily, as a kind of backup.  I'm afraid that multiple notifications for what seem like simple operations are common.  Windows file systems are no different.

Comment: Can you use `strace` to find out what modifications are done by the editor?

Comment: So there is no issue or i have not made any mistake in the code that i have written ?